# using awk on part of characters

Tags: awk

I'm trying to do awk to look for part of characters .

```
cat myfile.txt

SIFT    POLD    POLH    LRT     MT      MA
T       B       B       N       P       N
null    null    null    null    null    null
null    null    null    null    null    null
T;.;.;.;.;.     B       B       N       P       N
D       P       B       D       D       M
T       B       B       N       P       N
T;T;T;. B       B       N       P;P;P   N
D;.     P       B       N       P;P     .
T;.     B       B       N       P;P     .
```

In this example I want to get lines with SIFT = T (including "T;T;T;.") ; POLD = B; POLH = B; LRT = N; MT = P, MA = N

I would normally used awk to do the job , eg

```
awk -F'\t' '$1=="T" && $2=="B" && $3=="B" && $4=="N" && $5=="P" && $6=="N" myfile.txt
```

However, the command above will exclude "T;T;T;." in column 1. How can I include this too?

Comment: Is `($1 == "T" || $1 == "T;T;T;.")` far too obvious a solution?

Comment: Are you saying you wish to exclude `T;.` and `T;.;.;.;.;.`?  You need to be more precise.  Do you want to match lines in which any of the fields in column 1 is a T, or only the two lines with `T` and `T;T;T;.`, or something else?

Comment: "T;T;T;." is just one of the patterns in the first column . There are many other patterns that have a "T" in it. So basically , I want to get anything from column one that has a "T" . It can be "T;.;.;.;.;." or "T;T;T;. " and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` like below

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /T/' file
SIFT    POLD    POLH    LRT     MT      MA
T       B       B       N       P       N
T;.;.;.;.;.     B       B       N       P       N
T       B       B       N       P       N
T;T;T;. B       B       N       P;P;P   N
T;.     B       B       N       P;P     .
```

Comment: "T;T;T;." is just one of the patterns in the first column . There are many other patterns that have a "T" in it. So basically , I want to get anything from column one that has a "T" . It can be "T;.;.;.;.;." or "T;T;T;. " and so on.